# How to always makes a UIScrollView scrollable?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView`. The `scrollview.contentSize` is set to the height of all subviews in the `UIScrollView`. When the height of the `contentSize` if greater than the height of the `UIScrollView`, it is perfectly scrolling when dragging the view. When the height of the `contentSize` is less than the height of the `UIScrollView` nothing is happening when I drag the view.

I think that is standard behavior, since there is really nothing to scroll. But I would like, that the `UIScrollView` is moving a bit anyway.

A possible solution is to ensure, that the height of the contentSize is never less than the frame.height plus a small margin (i.e. 5px):

```
CGSize scrollSize = self.frame.size;
int defaultHeight = self.frame.size.height + 5;
int contentHeight = self.webView.frame.origin.y + self.webView.frame.size.height;
scrollSize.height = MAX(defaultHeight, contentHeight);
[self.scrollView setContentSize:scrollSize];
```

Is there a less hackish way to do this?

Comment: Do you just want it to bounce?

Comment: I assume that you tried setting `scrollEnabled` to `YES` manually, right?

Comment: Yes, I just want it to bounce -- and yes, `scrollEnabled=YES` didn't work.

Comment: Does it bounce when you have content in it?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

There are two properties on `UIScrollView` that sound like what you want:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL alwaysBounceVertical; // default NO. if YES and bounces is YES, even if content is smaller than bounds, allow drag vertically
@property(nonatomic) BOOL alwaysBounceHorizontal; // default NO. if YES and bounces is YES, even if content is smaller than bounds, allow drag horizontally
```

Simply set one or both of them to `YES` and you will get the bounce effect.

This can also be set in IB by checking the "Bounce Horizontally" and/or "Bounce Vertically" box(s):

[image]

Comment: Note that the solo "Bounces" checkbox has to be checked in addition to either "Bounce Horizontally" or "Bounce Vertically."

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey not for me

Answer (score 7):

In swift:

```
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
```