# iOS ScrollView/Bounce With Non-Scrolling Content

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I've seen some apps that have a small content area but give you that nice "iOS" effect of allowing you to bounce/pull down/scroll the view. Basically the exact effect as if using a UITableView.

I'm able to get that effect with a UIView/ScrollView when the content in the view exceeds the size of the phone, however how can I "enabled" it all the time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is what I'm looking for!

```
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting scrollView.bounces to YES

and scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical to YES/NO.

Comment: i hope this post may you help more :- 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446285/how-to-always-makes-a-uiscrollview-scrollable